# async await http request error catch is undefined

Tags: node.js, axios

I am doing async/await with axios http call:

```
try{ 
  let result = await axios.post('/user', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
}catch(err){
  // err is undefined if hit with http request error
  console.log(err.response.status) // undefined
}
```

but when i hit a request error, I get undefined err, why?

I am trying to get `err.response.status` and `err.response.data.error`

Comment: is this case, `err.response.status` is undefined, not `err`. Only try `console.log(err)` to see the output.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Fist of all..you are not returning or executing anything thing inside "try" block.. and plus you are not having "then" block. In order to get success or error you have to remove that "result" variable from try block...below there are two examples of axios you can try and that will work..

- first example..(complete axios method and the working one)

> ```
>  axios.post('/user', {
>     firstName: 'Fred',
>     lastName: 'Flintstone'
>   })
>   .then(function (response) {
>     console.log(response);
>   })
>   .catch(function (error) {
>     console.log(error);
>   });
> ```

- second example (axiom with try and catch block)

> ```
> try{ 
>   axios.post('/user', {
>     firstName: 'Fred',
>     lastName: 'Flintstone'
>   });
> }
> catch(err){
>   console.log(err);
> }
> ```

- But you dont need to use the second example because the first example is itself will work as try and catch block..In my opinion you should go with the first option..(more efficient one). hope this will help you.. happy coding B)

Comment: I am asking for the 2nd options, the console.log(err.response.data.error) is giving me undefined, that is what I mean.

Comment: thats what i am saying.. if you are not passing any response parameter then how will you get the response.status or error.. if you want response then try adding "then" method.. i m sure that will give you the result that you are looking for.. :)